# How can I return to my default Ubuntu shell

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I once changed the Ubuntu Shell by logging out and choosing a different shell from the top-right corner in the log-in box and now I do not know how to return to the default shell. Please help me as I just installed Ubuntu! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just repeat the process... and select the appropriate Desktop Environment I think the default/original is "Ubuntu".